# How to apply tsconfig.json to the Emacs org-babel?

Tags: typescript, emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I am using Emacs with org-babel mode to insert the TypeScript code example in my org-mode document.
The elisp I have added in `.emacs.d/init.el` is as follows:

```
(eval-after-load "org" '(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages '((typescript . t))))
(require 'typescript-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ts\\'" . typescript-mode))
(require 'tide)
```

Now, I want to make the following code as error:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC typescript :results output 
let data_1: string = undefined;
let data_2: string = null;
#+END_SRC
```

I think I can make it by specifying `tsconfig.json` as:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true,
  },
}
```

But where can I put `tsconfig.json`?

I modified `~/.emacs.d/elpa/tide-20200327.1218/tsserver/tsconfig.json` and restarded Emacs but nothing changed.

I ran `tsc` from the command line and confirmed `tsconfig.json` works as expected.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the code you've mentioned display an error, you can use the `:cmdline` parameter. That allows you to pass command line parameters (such as `--strictNullChecks`) directly  to `tsc`:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC typescript :cmdline --strictNullChecks :results output
let data_1: string = undefined;
let data_2: string = null;
#+END_SRC
```

I don't think you can use `tsconfig.json` to configure this, because to evaluate the code block, emacs first saves the code to a temp file (e.g.  `/tmp/babel-5NJb2Q/ob-input-Afjtyu`) and then runs the `tsc` on it (see [ob-typescript.el](https://github.com/lurdan/ob-typescript/blob/master/ob-typescript.el#L72)). That temp file bears no relation to your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion works for my purpose. And I understand I cannot use tsconfig.json.

Comment: You can specify header args per section (as a property) or per file (using the `#+PROPERTY` keyword) if you want to avoid duplication of the argument on every code block (or globally if you are *always* going to use the header arg). See [header args](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html#Using-Header-Arguments).